# How to compare anagrams without toCharArray method?

Tags: java

```
/*
 * 
 * 
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Anagram
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String one, two;

System.out.print("Enter first sentence: ");
String s1 = sc.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter second sentence: ");
String s2 = sc.nextLine();

sc.close();

s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
char[] chars = s1.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(chars);
String sort1 = new String(chars);
System.out.println(sort1 + " are the letters of " + s1 + " in order");

s2 = s2.toLowerCase();
char[] chars2 = s2.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(chars2);
String sort2 = new String(chars2);
System.out.println(sort2 + " are the letters of " + s2 + " in order");

if(sort1.equals(sort2))
  System.out.println(s1 + " is an anagram of " + s2);


  }
}
```

This is my program that works fine using toCharArray to compare anagrams, however would it be possible to do it finiding every 'a' to 'z' and append it to the sorted list instead of toCharArray?

Comment: So to clarify, you're looking for a way to compare only alphabetic characters from the strings (i.e. ignore numbers, punctuation, etc.)?

Comment: yes only comparing alphabetic characters that's right.

Comment: I also noticed when i test my program with words like replays and parsley it works or even Listen and Silent however when i try to use Shakespeare compared to Seek a phrase it will sort the letters but not define them as anagrams

Comment: Oh ok ignore the comment above i need to remove whitespaces

Comment: That's probably because of white space.  `Shakespeare` has zero space characters but `Seek a phrase` has two.  This would also be fixed if you found a way to only consider a-z

Comment: @Kevin K fixed the whitespace using s1 = s1.replaceAll(" ", ""); works like a charm still with toCharArray

Comment: Mmm, that gave me an idea for the general solution.  I posted an answer.

Comment: Modified to for (lower = 'a'; lower <='z'; lower++)
    if (lower.equals(s1));
    new1 += lower;
    System.out.println(new1);
however get this error
char cannot be dereferenced

Comment: (So you want to end up with the string "aaeeehkprss" for both.)

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a regular expression using the [`Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes to find characters within `"[a-zA-Z]"`.  You can then loop through the results

```
String string = "abcd123";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: when i substitute this code in mine at while (matcher.find()) i get an error illegal start of type

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a few options. If all you want to do is avoid the call to "toCharArray" then you can just loop through the string and create of characters that way, but I doubt this is what you're looking for?

You could also do an implementation as follows (pseudo-code):

```
public void areAnagrams(String s1, String s2)
{
  int[] aNumLetters = new int[26];

  s1.toLowerCase();
  s2.toLowerCase();

  for each char c in s1
    aNumLetters[(int)c - ((int)'a')]++;

  for each char c in s2
    aNumLetters[(int)c - ((int)'a')]--;

  for each int nLetterCount in aNumLetters
    if nLetterCount != 0
      return false

  return true;
}
```

Comment: if i don't want to return false or true and just append it to the sorted list, however i've used Array.sort and have no clue how to append it without the Array.sort method

Comment: @Ron_ish I'm not sure I understand what you mean. What do you want to append to the sorted list? What sorted list are you referring too? Are you saying that you are required to sort the letters?

Comment: if i find every 'a' in the lowercase sentence that i input and append it to the sorted string so for example using my method above my output would be for the words PARSLEY AND REPLAY - aelprsy are the letters of replays in order and compare that to the second one which would be aelprsy are the letters of parsley in order, finally compare both sorted and if they equal to each other therefore, they are anagrams

Comment: @Ron_ish I understand what you are doing in your algorithm, but what is your question regarding the algorithm I defined above? Are you saying that you are REQUIRED to sort all of the letters?

Comment: toCharArray is acceptable but yes as a home homework they want us to sort every single letter so an example for one could help me for all of them but yes all the letters are required

Answer (score 1):

If you do a naive search through a string for 'a' then 'b' and so on, then essentially you'll be performing a *bubble sort* which will have worse performance than `Arrays.sort()` which uses quicksort.

I would imagine the `toCharArray()` conversion has a negligible, one-time cost so trying to micro-optimize that away would be fruitless.

Instead—consider that for two strings to be anagrams it doesn't actually matter whether their sorted letters are equal, just that they have to contain the same number of each letter. That is, if a string contains 3 `A`'s and 1 `B` and 2 `N`'s then it's an anagram of `BANANA`.

Armed with that, we can conceivably compare whether two strings are anagrams simply by iterating through each character in the first string and building a `Map` of `<Character, Integer>` counts. Then iterate through the second string and do the reverse—decrement the count for each character.

After scanning the second string, you just need to check whether all counts are zero. One advantage of this approach is you can 'short-circuit' the checking whenever a character count goes below zero while scanning the second string—this means that the second string has more of that character than the first, so they're not anagrams.

The above outlines a best case `O(n)` algorithm (essentially, just one pass through each string) assuming best case of `O(1)` for map operations. On the worst case, we're looking at `O(n^2)`, I think.

Contrast this to quicksort, which has the same worst-case performance but `O(n log(n))` best case.

Of course, in practice quicksorting the character arrays might be faster for shorter strings. However, as the strings get substantially longer the above map-based algorithm should start to prove more efficient, esp. with the short-circuiting.

Comment: I would agree that toCharArray saves a lot of time rather than searching each single alphabetical letter however since it is homework and has specific working this is the way required so far. I will try your way as i have been trying all other alternatives too but i was just wondering how to do it by one alphabetical word at a time. Moreover it is also essential that our output shows a sorted alphabetical list for both words before deciding if they are anagrams

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single `String.replaceAll()` to remove all non-alphabetic characters from the string, and then the rest of your code should be correct.

This is because `String.replaceAll()` uses *regular expressions*.  Take a look at the [javadocs for Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for a quick reference on regular expressions in Java.  Pay special attention to the Character Classes section; from the examples you should be able to construct a pattern that matches "non-alphabetic characters".  Use that pattern for the first parameter, and empty string for second parameter in `String.replaceAll()`.

It's not the most efficient implementation in terms of performance, but probably is the simplest to code.